# Importing Apache Wink using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-luna, apache-wink

I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-useapachewink/) to install Wink.

**org.apache.wink.example**

When you get to the "Import Maven Projects" screen, it says you should see the following :

[image]

I just see this :

[image]

Any idea why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

You need add following information while adding the dependency. For Wink 1.4 maven dependency can be found from [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.wink.example%7Capps%7C1.4%7Cpom). You can add like shown in image:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wink.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>apps</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Please install subclipse first using eclipse market place.

[image]

and then search by providing dependency as shown below.

[image]

Comment: please post your own answer, steps to solve the problem, not images.